# Inconsistent word count on Microsoft Office Word

Tags: microsoft-word, word-count

I'm trying to track the word count of my documents. The solution seems to be accessing the `.xml` inside the `.docx` (`app.xml` after opening the `.docx` as a `.zip`). However, the numbers don't match:

Bottom bar: 164 712 words

Dialog (after counting time): 154 884 words (similar to LibreOffice count)

XML: 171 723 words

Is there anything I can do so that the `.xml` contains the second listed value?

Comment: Word doesn't update the app.xml consistently. Go to the Review tab, Proofing, Word Count and then make sure to save after. Does the app.xml then match the word count in the dialog?

Comment: I repeated the process three times to make sure, and there is no change so far. The values remain similar: 154 886 as the final count, and 153 608, 154 886, 171 702, and such for the bottom bar. The .xml now contains 171 725.

Comment: Is it possible that one of the counts omits headers, footers and/or footnotes? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc It's possible, I have a lot of headers. However, the final count and the .xml's value are the same (but different to each other, 154 886 and 171 725) whether the box is checked or not.